# Preloading an activity before displaying it?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am developing a game for android, it takes a few seconds of time to load everything before you can play. During this time or the splash screen, I would like to display a progress bar to show the user work is being done. Then kill the splash activity and launch my main activity.  I have a splash screen made with a progress bar calling a async function that only is working with the sleep function as a place holder for the progress bar to show information. It then takes a few seconds after its completed to launch the main activity. **The question is how do I load the activity and show the progress of it with the horizontal progress bar in the splash activity?** I've tried to fully understand the activity life cycle. I understand the `onCreate()` method creates the activity and then once it's finished then calls `onStart()` automatically.  But as stated before I want to just load the activity then start it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can not preload an `Activity` itself.

Instead you should try to load the data needed by that `Activity` within your splash screen.
When loaded, hand it over to your main `Activity`.
You can load images from disk/flash into memory, prepare internal data structures, things like that.
However, you can not create the layout or initialize the real main `Activity`.

Comment: Alright thanks,  how would I go about loading images and strings? That's mainly what's slowing me down. And possibly Google ads.

Comment: Load the strings and images into some kind of "in memory data structure" like `Bitmap` and `String` objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting the view via an xml file, this is relatively simple. The view is not inflated until you call `setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_XML_FILE);` Postpone calling this, or call it on another xml file with a simple infinite loading widget, then call the `setContentView()` on the real xml file when ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can't preload the `Activity`. Start the `Activity`, display the splash screen / progress bar, and load the data on another thread besides the main thread. Once the data is finished loading, switch the view with a `ViewFlipper`. I don't see a reason for multiple `Activity`'s.